# Python/Pandas - Combining 3 datasets into one column graph

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing basic data analysis right now and I'm struggling trying to create a column graph when theres 3 data sets.

Here's my data:

```
datasetArgentina = {'Year': ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007","2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015","2016"], 'Mortality': ['11000', '10000' ,'10000' ,'10000' ,'10000' ,'9300' ,'8900' ,'8700', '9000' , '8600' ,'8300' ,'8100','7800' ,'8000', '7500', '7500', '7300']}

datasetColumbia = {'Year': ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007","2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015","2016"], 'Mortality': ['1500 ','1600', '1500' ,'1600' ,'1500', '1200' ,'1300', '1400' ,'1400', '1500' ,'1500' ,'1500' ,'1600' ,'1500', '1500', '1400', '1400']}

datasetBrazil = {'Year': ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007","2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015","2016"], 'Mortality': ['11000', '10000' ,'10000' ,'10000' ,'10000' ,'9300' ,'8900' ,'8700', '9000' , '8600' ,'8300' ,'8100','7800' ,'8000', '7500', '7500', '7300']}
```

What are some recommendations to go about converting this into one big column graph, and have the countries in different colours?

This is my poor attempt at combining the data sets together and printing it out.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datasetArgentina)
df5 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datasetColumbia)
df6 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datasetBrazil)

df7 = pd.merge(df4, df5, on='Year')
df8 = pd.merge(df6, df7, on='Year', how='left')
print(df7)
print(df8)

plt.bar(df8['Year'], df8['Mortality'])
plt.title('South America')
plt.xticks(df8['Year'], rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Mortality')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Any help would be great.

Output:

```
df7   Mortality_x  Year Mortality_y
0        11000  2000       1500 
1        10000  2001        1600
2        10000  2002        1500
3        10000  2003        1600
4        10000  2004        1500
5         9300  2005        1200
6         8900  2006        1300
7         8700  2007        1400
8         9000  2008        1400
9         8600  2009        1500
10        8300  2010        1500
11        8100  2011        1500
12        7800  2012        1600
13        8000  2013        1500
14        7500  2014        1500
15        7500  2015        1400
16        7300  2016        1400
df8   Mortality  Year Mortality_x Mortality_y
0      11000  2000       11000       1500 
1      10000  2001       10000        1600
2      10000  2002       10000        1500
3      10000  2003       10000        1600
4      10000  2004       10000        1500
5       9300  2005        9300        1200
6       8900  2006        8900        1300
7       8700  2007        8700        1400
8       9000  2008        9000        1400
9       8600  2009        8600        1500
10      8300  2010        8300        1500
11      8100  2011        8100        1500
12      7800  2012        7800        1600
13      8000  2013        8000        1500
14      7500  2014        7500        1500
15      7500  2015        7500        1400
16      7300  2016        7300        1400
```

[image: Arg]
[image: Bra]

Comment: What is df4, df5, df6, and df7? What happened to dfs 1 through 3?

Comment: Hi Coldspeed, I removed some code because df1 to df3 was used to obtain the data from the CSV file, and I wanted to be concise about what help I need.

Comment: Okay, can you explain your expected output for the given data?

Comment: Okay, I've edited the post to show the output of df7 and df8. I'm thinking of just scrapping the code if there's an easy way to combine them, as the output spits out "Mortality, Mortality_x, Mortality_y" whereas I wanted to label those by country

Comment: When you column graph, do you mean a stacked bar plot by country?

Comment: I've attached some images of the graphs I'm talking about. So basically I want to combine those two, and one more graph together. If it's easier to do a stacked bar plot, I'm all ears !

Comment: Okay, I think I understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `seaborn` with `factorplot` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib inline

datasetArgentina = {'Year': ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007","2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015","2016"], 'Mortality': ['11000', '10000' ,'10000' ,'10000' ,'10000' ,'9300' ,'8900' ,'8700', '9000' , '8600' ,'8300' ,'8100','7800' ,'8000', '7500', '7500', '7300']}

datasetColumbia = {'Year': ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007","2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015","2016"], 'Mortality': ['1500 ','1600', '1500' ,'1600' ,'1500', '1200' ,'1300', '1400' ,'1400', '1500' ,'1500' ,'1500' ,'1600' ,'1500', '1500', '1400', '1400']}

datasetBrazil = {'Year': ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007","2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015","2016"], 'Mortality': ['11000', '10000' ,'10000' ,'10000' ,'10000' ,'9300' ,'8900' ,'8700', '9000' , '8600' ,'8300' ,'8100','7800' ,'8000', '7500', '7500', '7300']}


df4 = pd.DataFrame(datasetArgentina)
df5 = pd.DataFrame(datasetColumbia)
df6 = pd.DataFrame(datasetBrazil)
```

Additional codes:

```
# add country field for each dataframe
df4['country'] = 'Argentina'    
df5['country'] = 'Columbia'
df6['country'] = 'Brazil'

# Combine all dataframes
df = pd.concat([df4,df5,df6])
# convert to float
df['Mortality'] = df['Mortality'].astype(float)

sns.factorplot(data=df, hue='country', x='Year', y='Mortality', kind='bar', ci=None, aspect=3, size=7);
plt.xticks(rotation=45);
```

Result (*for more you can look into `seaborn` and `factorplot`*):

[image: result image]

Comment: Hi mate, that is absolutely amazing what you have done. I'll definitely look at seaborn and factorplot, because my initial code just had pandas/matplotlib/numpy. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! `Happy coding`.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate your dataframes using `concat`, and then group and plot them by country using `groupby` + `plot`:

```
df = pd.concat(
       [df4, df5, df6], keys=['Argentina', 'Columbia', 'Brazil']
)

df.astype(int).groupby(level=0).plot.bar(x='Year', y='Mortality');
plt.show()
```

This gives you separate plots for each group.